# Azure Function App Url changing by itself

Tags: function, azure, url, key, azure-functions

I have a Azure function app (v1), I noticed calls to it stopped, on inspection the code at the end of the url had changed. I am certain it worked before in previous day, this code I believe comes from the key, we have used it in our calling app.

No deployments have occurred to the app for many days. Do microsoft turn these keys every so often? Could there be any other reason it changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be running into a rare race condition in key generation. There is a fix for it that should be released by the end of next week. The PR that fixed it is here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/pull/3590.

Comment: This sounds like it could be the case, its highly odd as the url is documented and was working, very few people have access to change it. We will keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Azure doesn't rotate function secrets in silence unless

1. We change `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType` in Application settings.
2. We happen to delete files containing keys.

Explanation:

Azure Functions currently supports two key storage mechanisms: file system and blob storage.

By default Functions V1 use file system, V2 use blob. We can set AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType to switch the mode. Secrets are regenerated other than being copied the first time we switch the mode.

- For file system, we can find the encrypted secrets on kudu(`https://functionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`) and navigate to `D:\home\data\functions\secrets`.

  If our Function app is on consumption plan, we can also trace them in Storage account specified by `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING`(same as `AzureWebJobsStorage` by default if we don't change), under File Share named by app setting `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE`, directory `home\data\functions\secrets`.
- For blob, go to blob container `azure-webjobs-secrets` in the Storage account specified by `AzureWebJobsStorage` app setting.

If we accidentally delete those file, Azure will generate new secrets.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, we use v1 with file storage, but not changed any of that. Going to have to keep an eye on it as very few people had access to change this and its only happened before when Microsoft released v2

Comment: @User101 You may meet the condition as brettsam described if no one changed the key or modified related settings.